# Generate a PHP UTF-16 SHA1 hash to match C# method

Tags: c#, php, unicode, encoding, sha1

I'm trying to replicate some C# code in PHP5 and am having some difficulties.

The C# code is as following, and it is important to note that it cannot be changed:

```
string s = strToHash;
UnicodeEncoding encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(s);
SHA1Managed managed = new SHA1Managed();     
bytes = encoding.GetBytes(Convert.ToBase64String(managed.ComputeHash(bytes)) + "Space");
return Convert.ToBase64String(managed.ComputeHash(bytes));
```

The PHP code I've written to replicate this is as follows:

```
utfString = mb_convert_encoding($strToHash,"UTF-16");
hashTag = sha1($utfString,true); 
base64Tag = base64_encode($hashTag); 
encodedBase64Tag = mb_convert_encoding($base64Tag."Space","UTF-16");
base64EncodedAgain = base64_encode($encodedBase64Tag);

echo $base64EncodedAgain
```

However, the two outputs don't match up.
I believe this is because the SHA1 method in PHP works on ASCII encoded strings, not the encoding actually used by the passed in string.

I would like to get this to work, and I can't achieve it by altering the c# code (although no-doubt that would be the easiest fix).

Please can any advise on some ideas?

---

OK, I have altered the code following Artefacto's advice, and it still isn't working as expected.

The PHP Code now looks like this:

```
$utfString = "\xFF\xFE".mb_convert_encoding($strToHash,"UTF-16LE");
$hashTag = sha1($utfString,true);       
$base64Tag = base64_encode($hashTag);   
$encodedBase64Tag = "\xFF\xFE".mb_convert_encoding($base64Tag."Space","UTF-16LE");  
$hashedAgain = sha1($encodedBase64Tag,true);
$base64EncodedAgain = base64_encode($hashedAgain);

echo $base64EncodedAgain."<Br/>";
```

And the outputed value of this method is:

> 1/Y5MCzI8vDJqc456YIicpwoyy0=

However, from the C# code, the value is this:

> VPf7BhT1ksAfWbzeJw35g+bVKwY=

Comment: Why do you concatenate "Space" to the base64 encoded hash?

Comment: "I" didn't.. but I suspect it's to add a extra level of (basic) encryption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, try this code:

```
$utfString = mb_convert_encoding($strToHash,"UTF-16");
$hashTag = sha1($utfString,true); 
$base64Tag = base64_encode($hashTag); 
$encodedBase64Tag = mb_convert_encoding($base64Tag."Space","UTF-16");
$base64EncodedAgain = base64_encode(sha1($encodedBase64Tag, true));

echo $base64EncodedAgain
```

Because you miss one `sha1` call.

### Update

Now this code should work:

```
$utfString = mb_convert_encoding($strToHash,"UTF-16LE");
$hashTag = sha1($utfString,true);       
$base64Tag = base64_encode($hashTag);   
$encodedBase64Tag = mb_convert_encoding($base64Tag."Space","UTF-16LE");  
$hashedAgain = sha1($encodedBase64Tag,true);
$base64EncodedAgain = base64_encode($hashedAgain);
echo $base64EncodedAgain . "<br />";
```

Comment: thanks for pointing that out :)
Sadly, it wasn't the overall issue tho.

Answer (score 2):

The docs for the [no-arg constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8hs5kkbk.aspx) of `UnicodeEncoding` say this:

> This constructor creates an instance that uses the little endian byte order, provides a Unicode byte order mark, and does not throw an exception when an invalid encoding is detected.

Now, `mb_convert_encoding` assumes "UTF-16" as "UTF-16BE" (big-endian). It also does not provide a BOM. Therefore, you must do instead:

```
$utfString = "\xFF\xFE" . mb_convert_encoding($strToHash,"UTF-16LE");
/* ...*/
$encodedBase64Tag = "\xFF\xFE" . mb_convert_encoding($base64Tag."Space","UTF-16LE");
```

As [Paja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298609/paja) pointed out, you're also missing a call to `sha1`.

Comment: I tried this, but as shown in my edited comment now, the results are still very different.
Have I done something wrong?

Comment: @Sk93 It doesn't help. Post the UTF-16 data that `encoding.GetBytes` (in the two occasions).

Answer (score 0):

1. This code should work...

   ```
   $utfString = mb_convert_encoding($strToHash,"UTF-16LE");
   $hashTag = sha1($utfString,true);
   $base64Tag = base64_encode($hashTag);
   echo $base64Tag;
   ```